# Create Axios instance generate 404 in GET method of nextjs route.ts

Tags: next.js, axios

I just want use Axios in NextJS with instantiation in api route. If I put instance into a route.ts then I get 404 route not found error generated by NextJS client side. If I comment out code in route everithing is fine. (*edited: I added an agent to axios, please see image below)

I use next "13.4.19", axios "^1.5.0".

Here is the axiosInstance.ts

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
});
```

and here is the route.ts:

```
import axiosInstance from "@/lib/axiosInstance";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

//*
function axiosGet() {
    axiosInstance.get('/api/v2/tenant').then((response) => {
        return NextResponse.json(response.data, { status: 200 });
    }).catch((error) => {
        return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' }, { status: 500 })
    })
}
//*/

export async function GET() {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Hello World' }, { status: 200 });
}
```

I don't understand why. Please help me.

[image: my folder structure]

[image: 404 message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a misstake in cert paths (project root dir contains the cert files). I changed it and error is gone.

```
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
    cert: fs.readFileSync('client.crt'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('client.key'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.pem'),
});
```